# Any app I try to build crashes on the Unity splash screen

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, unity-game-engine

Please, somebody help me. I've been struggling with my problem for two days, I surfed all Internet and didn't find anything. I use Unity to make games for iDevices. Everything was just fine when I used Snow Leopard with xCode 4.0, but now I have Lion and xCode 4.2 and I can't build ANY app. I tried 5 different projects, and I even tried to make totally blank app, but every project I try to build in xCode to my device just closes on splash screen without any error. xCode just says that app finished running. I tried on iPod 4 and iPhone 3Gs - same. This is killing me! Please, someone help!

Comment: Do you use Unity3D 3.4.2? What iOS version? Can you build for web player / Mac OSX? Can you edit your question and provide a screenshot of the build settings? Did you read http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/108301-iOS-fail-in-epic-fashion? The 5 projects: From you or sample projects as well?

Comment: Yes, Unity 3.4.2, iOS 4.2.1. Yes, the game has no problem with mac os or web player or android. The link above don't seem to help me at all. Yes, 5 mine projects. I tried to build the game, that once was successfully built and released with xCode 4.0, and the same - it's just crashes on a splash screen without error both on iPod 4 and iPhone 3gs. I am in total despair.

Comment: OK not very original: I once had a similar problem and finally solved by rebooting the device. Remove the app from device. Play with the build settings: release/debug, iphone only, no optimisation, replace project. What is the build output from XCode after CMD+B? Can you step into AppController.mm with the debugger?

Comment: I've tried everything. No result. I've removed xCode from Mac and reinstalled it, I've updated my iPod os to iOS 5.0 - still NOTHING!!! I am pulling my hair out for three days! This can't be true. How come that this kind of bug exists in xCode and no one knows about it?! What possibly can I try else? Kill the Lion and install Snow Leopard with xCode 4.0? Is this really only option?

Comment: (1) Post a screenshot of your iOS player settings and the most important settings in XCode. Often the settings in XCode are messed up. (2) Post the problem to forum.unity3d.com and answers.unity3d.com. There you find more people working with Unity Pro

Answer (score 1):

Finally problem solved! I've just removed Unity 3.4.2 and installed Unity 3.4.0 and it worked! Strange bug, I've spent three days blaming Apple, wouldn't think that this problem would be from Unity side.

Answer (score 1):

> Finally problem solved! I've just removed Unity 3.4.2 and installed
>   Unity 3.4.0 and it worked! Strange bug, I've spent three days blaming
>   Apple, wouldn't think that this problem would be from Unity side.

I just had the inverse problem...
I switched from 3.4.0 to 3.4.2 now nothing is working anymore...

Is there something new to do? I just re-created my whole Xcode project with all the storekits, openfeint and all and nothing works. It crashes on Unity splashscreen

Comment: Can you tell me if the Unity3D project was done from a Windows machine or a MAC machine? The same issue here but my case might be little bit different; the code was done on a Windows machine :)